# Clay Shirky's references to Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange at LinuxCon

Tags: discussion, research

At [LinuxCon North America 2011](http://events.linuxfoundation.org/events/linuxcon/shirky) [Clay Shirky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clay_Shirky) mentioned Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow. In *[Clay Shirky Says Good Collaboration is Structured Fighting](https://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2011/08/clay-shirky-says-good-collabor.php)*, Joe Brockmeier reported from the presentation:

> As an example of putting barriers to contribution, Shirky
>       pointed to Stack Overflow [Stack Exchange, Area 51]. In 
>       order to test whether a new site would work well, they don't just let people try
>       anything to see what sticks. People have to propose a
>       site, demonstrate the type of questions, and then
>       recruit users. Sites that don't make the criteria don't
>       launch, but the ones that do launch tend to be more
>       successful.

and

> New users can't participate easily either. Shirky talked
>       about the karma system for Stack Overflow, which requires
>       users to show up and listen at the beginning – and
>       evolve to an admin-level status that can manage the
>       site.

And somewhat more verbose by Ruth Suehle in *[Clay Shirky on structured fighting, technology, and all the squishy, human stuff](http://opensource.com/life/11/8/clay-shirky-structured-fighting-technology-and-all-squishy-human-stuff)* :

> Stack Overflow has implemented a karma system, like 
>     countless other participatory websites. And, also like 
>     many others (including opensource.com), they've added a 
>     layer of badges to the karma system. But unlike most 
>     others, the badges aren't just "achievement unlocked." 
>     They're using karma to enforce restricted participation. 
>     When you show up to Stack Overflow as a new user, all you 
>     can do is listen. You can't post a question or answer. You 
>     just have to be quiet, read, and see how the community 
>     works. Newcomers to many communities receive this advice--
>     take some time to observe before getting involved--but few 
>     heed it. Stack Overflow enforces it.
>
> On the other end of the spectrum, at 10,000 points, you 
>     essentially become a moderator. You're given the ability 
>     to shut down things you consider inappropriate without 
>     being a part of the site's management. Once you've proven 
>     you're trustworthy, you're rewarded with the ability to 
>     act as if the site is your own.

---

Is a video of Clay Shirky's presentation available somewhere?

Comment: "When you show up to Stack Overflow as a new user, all you can do is listen. You can't post a question or answer. You just have to be quiet, read, and see how the community works". Er...

Comment: Yes, Ruth Suehle (or Clay Shirky) got it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for posting this.  I posted a comment on the first article.  Others had already beat me to it on the second.

Comment: How did LinuxCon go, by the way?